# Error connecting to SSAS from power bi report server on premises

Tags: powerbi, ssas, power-bi-report-server

I built a report with power bi Desktop RS, connect it to SSAS tabular, everything is working normally, but when I deploy the report to Power bi report server on premises:

I got an error that it can't connect to the Analytics services server.

Power bi report server version: September

My power bi desktop version: September

the connection to the SSAS server is test with:

```
telnet SSASserver 2383
```

it's working.

the error screenshot:

[image]

the connection is working before I deploy it using power bi desktop but when save it to the report server it's not.

Comment: Does it work if you RDP into the Report Server and browse from there?  If so you might need to set up Kerberos Constrained Delegation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/configure-kerberos-powerbi-reports

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it works from inside the server if I opened it with Power bi desktop RS, but when I deploy to the report server portal (inside the server) it can't connect, so strange.
to summarize: I am RDP into the server, the report works fine with PBI desktop, I save the dashboard to the server, I click take there --> it opens the portal but the report can't connect to the SSAS server (which is in another server)